# Xamarin doesn't deploy to real Android device

Tags: android, xamarin, deployment, build, device

I have a really weird problem, I created an Android project, it worked perfectly and deployed to my real device, but after deleting that project in my computer and then download it from tfs, it builds correctly and deploy to emulator, but in the emulator after some time running and self-closing it's gonna work, but when I deploy it to my real device, it says deploy succeeded but it doesn't really deployed! I don't know why! if I create a new project it work perfectly, this issue happens only when I retrieve my project from tfs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, I install a copy that previously kept on my device and then uninstall it, then the deployment gonna work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Further if you want to uninstall it, uninstall it for all users.

Comment: hope that would help you :)